# Creating custom Insert Media page

Tags: plugin-development, media-library

I'm writing a plugin, that has the basically the same functionality as Insert Media page in "Add media" popup. The only difference mine has to use web service for browsing media. I already read about `media_upload_tabs` and managed to create a tab.

Now I'd like to have the **exact** same layout as Insert media tab, but unfortunately my media tab is an iframe (ugly) and doesn't have any CSS styles (or JS) attached.

How can I print required CSS styles (I think I'll rewrite the JS part in Angular) in my tab? I've tried to enqueue some basic styles but couldn't find how to print them or how they are named.

EDIT: As requested, some code, changed a bit to hide the name of the plugin

First for adding custom tab:

```
function something_upload_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['something'] = 'something';
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'media_upload_tabs', 'something_upload_tab' );
```

Then for displaying the tab:

```
function something_upload_tab_content() {
    require('views/something.php');
}
add_action('media_upload_something','something_upload_tab_content');
```

`views/something.php` is is a bunch of HTML copied from Insert Media tab. It isn't important except for one line (or a few more maybe) I am missing to put there proper styling for WordPress admin panel.

Comment: You get answers faster if you provide your code to create the tab.

Comment: The code is basically the same HTML as in original Insert Media tab. I copied it 1:1 from the generated page and I would like to Angular-ise it ;) I'm just looking for a method to attach CSS from admin panel to my custom tab.

Comment: The key is: If we can just take your code to [create a simple plugin from it](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2572/73), we can test our answer faster. That’s just a recommendation.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I updated the question with the code.